# How get the values of multi entries (when added in fly by jQuery) in view of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create() {
            Number newNumber = new Number();
        return View(newNumber);
    }
```

and View :

```
@model PhoneBook.Models.Number
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<h2>Create</h2>
<script src="../../Scripts/jQuery.AddNewNumber.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Contact.Id)
<fieldset>
<legend>Number</legend>
<div class="TargetElements">
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NumberKind)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.NumberKind.Title, NumberKinds)
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    <input class="AddNew" value="Add New" type="button" /></p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</p>
</fieldset>
}
```

By press AddNew button (use jQuery AddNewNumber.js) new input+DropDown Added to form in client side. this is script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.AddNew').click(function () {
    var targetcloneelements = $(".TargetElements:first").clone();
    targetcloneelements.find('input').val('');
    targetcloneelements.insertAfter('.TargetElements:last');
});
});
```

This way(Add new) is very usual, All of us can see that in many sites (So that must have a solution), But there is a problem in retrieve values. When I have one entry element(include input+DropDown) I can retrieve values like the following in post of my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Number NewNumber, FormCollection collection) {
            db.Numbers.Add(NewNumber);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index")
}
```

I read this articles : [1](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx#s8-binding-with-a-list-of-class-types) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198651/how-do-i-create-multiple-entries-in-one-view-in-c-sharp-asp-net-mvc) , [3](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx) but none of them haven't any solution for fly mode add entries, when I know the numbers of entity it can be possible but in fly mode it can be 1 or 1000

So, is there any way to retrieve values and add them to DataBase?

**Edit:**

I find the values in FormCollection but yet I don't know how extract them from collection? This is a picture of the Collection values in breakponit of binding

[image: Pic]

**Edit2:**

Find to retrieve all values: (every element has a key that seen in above pic)

```
string[] PhoneNumbers = collection.GetValues("PhoneNumber");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every element has a key so you can use this for example:

```
string[] PhoneNumbers = collection.GetValues("PhoneNumber");
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is called Model binding to a List of object and your case it's Non-Sequential.

ASP.NET MVC `DefaultModelBinder` can bind arbitrary object if you follow a described convention like below:

> **Non-Sequential Indices**
>
> What happens when you can’t guarantee that the submitted values will
>   maintain a sequential index? For example, suppose you want to allow
>   deleting rows before submitting a list of books via JavaScript.
>
> The good news is that by introducing an extra hidden input, you can
>   allow for arbitrary indices. In the example below, we provide a hidden
>   input with the .Index suffix for each item we need to bind to the
>   list. The name of each of these hidden inputs are the same, so as
>   described earlier, this will give the model binder a nice collection
>   of indices to look for when binding to the list.

you can read the whole article from : http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Here is the code sample:

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/Create">

    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="cold" />
    <input type="text" name="products[cold].Name" value="Beer" />
    <input type="text" name="products[cold].Price" value="7.32" />

    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="123" />
    <input type="text" name="products[123].Name" value="Chips" />
    <input type="text" name="products[123].Price" value="2.23" />

    <input type="hidden" name="products.Index" value="caliente" />
    <input type="text" name="products[caliente].Name" value="Salsa" />
    <input type="text" name="products[caliente].Price" value="1.23" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You controller action should look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<Product> products) {

    foreach(var item in products) { 

        //play with your product here.
    }
}
```

Also, see the following articles as well:

> **Editing a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style**
>
> http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/
>
> **Validating a variable length list, ASP.NET MVC 2-style**
>
> http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/validating-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Those two articles for **ASP.NET MVC 2** but works same on **ASP.NET MVC 3**.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you add also a new form with a new submit button and submit ONLY the new values?

Of course the old and new form don't have to be nested, since they shouldn't work.

I did it several times, but with a slight different approach.
Your js function should make a post async call to a method that returns a partial view with the whole new form.

Comment: That's not bad, but for any new entry the client user must press submit button, it can be 1000 click rather than one click.

Comment: yes you're right, but this way you have atomic control on any data: guess a user inserting 50 new contacts and first is wrong. Do you want to invalidate the other 49 also? Isn't it better to invalidate only what is inserting? On the other hand (but it's not a very plus) you have also a less bandwidth usage. IMHO.

Comment: hmm, I don't sure about less bandwidth usage, but I think this way(add new entry and submit once) is very usual and what they do for handle it? beside your answer, I am interested in a way for one submit.

Answer (score 0):

I am not much knowledgeable about ASP.Net .

But from php & ROR this how it can be made to work.

give the html of input as follow

`<input name='some-name[]' class='blah-blah' />`

The main idea is to use `[]` that indicates that this named param would have multiple values .

And in your server side script you can receive it as `some-name[0]` & `some-name[1]` as if it was an array. simple.. try it out.